# How to patch kernel to get some hardware working

Tags: 12.04, kernel, vaio, patch

**Some info:** I have a patch file `vaio-full-3.2.2.patch` which I downloaded from [here](http://www.absence.it/vaio-acpi/source/patches/?C=M;O=D). Well, if I patch the kernel with it, it is supposed to get some hardware working, such as the light sensor that controls the lcd's brightness and the keyboard's backlight and some other things ([See](http://code.google.com/p/vaio-f11-linux/)). It's for sony vaio f11 series. My laptop is a f111fx, dual-boot win7/ubuntu 12.04 with kernel: `3.8.0-35-generic`.

Well, *What am I supposed to do?! :-)* Will it work for me? Experienced guys please help me understand what I am exactly gonna do.

(I'm kinda newbie in Linux programming, kernel hacking, etc. I'm not a beginner programmer though. I know matlab, latex, some C++ and some python but the fact is I haven't worked with linux much.)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, applying a patch to a kernel x versions newer, is unlikely to succeed. You might be able to hack in the changes by hand, but that is a lot of work and is not future proof.

Since you are on 12.04, an alternative might be to upgrade your kernel. Looking at the last year a lot of improvements have been made for Sony laptops: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?qt=grep&q=sony-laptop

Maybe you can first try to download and install a Live Linux distro (for example on CD or USB) with a fairly new kernel, to see if the problem is already fixed. From here you can make the choice to upgrade your current distribution/kernel or go for the manual method.

Comment: @Arthure Thanks for the answer. I'll do. I hope it'll work. I have a long way with this linux though.

Comment: Cheers. Let me know if it worked out for you.